# backbone and codeigniter rest server issues

Tags: php, codeigniter, backbone.js

My frontend is backbone and frontend is codeigniter with Phil Sturgeon’s REST Controller.

I have one model: Publisher
and one collection: Publishers

```
App.Collections.Publishers = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Models.Publisher,
    url: '/restpublisher'
});
```

my RestPublisher controller has:

```
 function index_post(){
    $this->response('in pulisher_post');

}

function index_delete(){
    $this->response('in pulisher_delete');

}

function index_put(){
    $this->response('in pulisher_put');
}
```

The problem is that on this.model.save(); the url that is fired is: http://pubhub.local/restpublisher/1111 where 1111 is the id.

problem is that i get 404. if i just simulate a put request to http://pubhub.local/restpublisher/ everything works fine and i guess i can get the params from request->put()

is there a way to solve this problem?

question 2: can someone please explain me why the name of the action should start with index?
why can't i just write action: publishers_post that on save of the collection will get the data?

Thanks a Lot!
Roy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start with the second question: I guess it's just easier to parse, and it'll just be boilerplate anyway, so why not index_?

Now, to go on with the interesting part. If your work with models inside a collection, Backbone, as a default behavior, will use the collection's URL to build a default one for your model (*collection.url/model.id*). However, you can override this by setting a value for your model's URL: `url: '/restpublisher'`.

[Source](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url)

**Edit:**
To give you the general idea of how it works, it's easier to quote Backbone's Model#url code:

```
url: function() {
  var base = _.result(this, 'urlRoot') || _.result(this.collection, 'url') || urlError();
  if (this.isNew()) return base;
  return base + (base.charAt(base.length - 1) === '/' ? '' : '/') + encodeURIComponent(this.id);
}
```

So basically, if you override the `url` attribute in your model, this function will be erased, and the behavior you don't want as well.

Comment: Backbone model is inheriting from the collection url thus it's already have url: "/restpublisher".  this is really not the problem at all... the problem is that backbone produce the url http://pubhub.local/restpublisher/1111 where codeigniter expect a url: http://pubhub.local/restpublisher without the id attached

Comment: The model isn't inheriting anything (I'm not sure the term *inherit* is adapted anyway). The URL is evaluated on the fly when needed if not specified in the model. Here if you specify one, it will no longer use the collection's URL. Exactly the behavior you need.

Comment: I could look into it, but as I've never used CodeIgniter, I guess that'll be pretty slow because I'd have to understand the mechanisms of the REST API first.